# Unix permissions and PHP

Tags: php, unix, file-permissions

I still try to figure out the different unix file permissions in context with PHP. I have a public folder, which is owned by the web server www-data and belongs to the group gr-a. 7 means write access with execute permission, 5 read access with execute permissions and so on.

But I don't know what is meant with "execute permission". Does a PHP file need them? What is the best file permission for a simple index.php file?

Now we assume I have a file test.php which should be writeable and readable for the developers Alice and Bob. I put them into the group gr-a. Is the file permission 775 now the right one?

Does apache needs writeaccess? Does the rest of the world need readaccess or only www-data? So would 770 be useful? Or is 660 better?

Thanks a lot for helping me!

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/46371/543011

Comment: Thanks a lot! This link is really helpful. But I still do not know what to do if I have many users. Do you have a solution for the following scenario: Alice and Bob are developing in /var/www/projectA. Charlie and Dora are developing in /var/www/ProjectB. Alice and Bob should write and read in projectA, but not in ProjectB and vice versa.

Comment: I really don't get it. Now I have the file index.php which is owned by the user www-data and the group dev-a. I am a member of the group and the permission for the file is 0660, 0770 for the dictionary. I can't access the file anymore. I thought as a member of the group I have write and read permissions. But the system trades me like a "other"-user.

Comment: I think you need execute permissions on the directory.